# How can I avoid long if - else in Factory?

Tags: xml, if-statement, factory

I have a Factory that create from xml file, is that possible to avoid long if - else, if the xml is dynamic and I don't want to hardcode the objects ?
Java code-

```
public static IDevice createDevice(String name, Element element) {
    IDevice device;
    if (name.equals("Autopilot")) {
        String strSpeed = element.getAttribute("maxSpeed");
        int speed = Integer.parseInt(strSpeed);
        device = new AutoPilot(speed);
        return device;
    } else if (name.equals("Camera")) {
        device = new CameraDevice();
        return device;
    } else if (name.equals("ClassifiedDevice")) {
        device = new ClassifiedDevice();
        return device;
    }

    return null;

}
```

There are "devices" in xml file with different properties, and factory creates them depending of which are selected to create. But the device list is dynamic and can be expanded  in the future.

```
<UAV>
<Device name="Autopilot"        maxSpeed  =  "70"    minSpeed  =  "40"    />
<Device name="Camera"           maxRange  =  "7000"                       />
<Device name="ClassifiedDevice"   range   =  "8000"  time      =  "4"     />
</UAV>
```

Comment: Show some codez man

Comment: And what is your factory supposed to do? Read xml, and create what kind of things based on that? And using what language?

Comment: Assuming that this is Java, there are many possible answers, but my first port of call would be questioning whether you need all these different classes in the first place. And if the answer to that is "yes", then whether there is any value in the `IDevice` interface and this factory. If the answer is still "yes", you can look at things like JAXB/XStream (which do the xml deserialisation for you based on rules you specify) or using an enum or map to store your creation strategies.

Comment: You don't need a new class when you just want to give an object a new name. You can do that with one class and assign the object a property `Name`. Please show us the IDevice interface.

Comment: It's not a real project, I'm a student and we are stying xml now.  The classes are temporarily differ only in name, they are going to be filled with absolutely different logic, I think the fact that thy have name is the only thing they have in common. As for IDevice - it's empty, I created and implemented it in all devices so the would have something in common so I could create ArrayList in future of devices with something more specific then Object.

Comment: @AntonKuznetsov That's where my question comes in: what's the value of a method that creates objects with no useful shared behaviour? Think about what happens when someone calls that method. They get an object of type `IDevice`, but that interface is empty and therefore doesn't say anything about how to use that object. So the caller will have to figure out what the actual class of the object returned is and cast it to it, possibly through another, equally lengthy switch-case statement. At which point you really haven't won anything by combining all these individual factories into one.

Comment: @biziclop Well, the idea is - there is going to be an xml file with all possible devices, and additional xml config file with list of devices for this particular instance of UAV. The NodeList will load installed devices from said config file, and for loop will run on the list, create instances of the devices via factory and add them to ArrayList of installed devices. Again, I'm a student, if there is an easier way to do it, please, tell me how, because thats the easiest one I see.

Comment: The only advice I can give is to think about what happens afterwards. Don't worry too much about this method and how objects are loaded for the time being, just write the rest of your program. Then when you're done, you can revisit this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, if you want to avoid long `else if`s you can (depending on your language, but I guess it's C# or maybe Java) use a `switch` statement. Is it that what you're looking for?

For example in C# (might look the same in Java, not sure):

```cs
switch(name)
{
    case "Autopilot":
        var strSpeed = element.getAttribute("maxSpeed");
        var speed = int.parse(strSpeed);
        return new AutoPilot(speed);
        return device;
    //other cases  ...
    default:
        // unknown device?
        // return some default value or thrown exception or whatever you want :D
}
```

You could also try a functional approach, maybe like this:
(Note: this is C#, I have no idea if this works in Java, but as far as I know there should be an equivalent)

```cs
var factories = new Dictionary<string, Func<IDevice>>
{
    { "Autopilot", ()=>{
        string strSpeed = element.getAttribute("maxSpeed");
        var speed = int.parse(strSpeed);
        return new AutoPilot(speed);
        }
    },
    // more "cases"
    //{ "", ... }
};

//simply call by:
IDevice device = factories[name](); // maybe check if the name is in the dictionary first...
```

Comment: It works in Java, just replace `()=>` with `()->` :)

Comment: Who ever downvoted, please explain why, I'm still learning myself so it would be nice of you to tell me what's wrong or could be improved.. Thank you :)

Comment: No idea who down voted. I liked the solution with lambda expressions, but the switch case is not exactly what I had in mind